# List of invhist_transtypes from xtuple

Tags: xtuple

I am in need the of meaning behind the 2 letter codes in the following column in xtuple:

```
public.invhist.invhist_transtypes
```

some examples in records are IM AD and CC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while, but I found this link which should have everything I need and I want to document it for the world because it was a bit hard to find.

This is the list as of 12/31/2019
 [image]

https://manuals.xtuple.com/refguide/current/Section461282.html